# Remove sliding toggle effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having a little trouble removing an over elaborate jquery slide effect for a simple close div id button.

I simply want to flick closed - no animation what so ever.

My HTML:

```
<div class="d-all t-all m-all group following_prompt">
<button type='button' id='hideshow' value='hide/show' class="close"><span class="icon-cross black right"></span></button>
    <section class="center group">
        <h1>You're not following anyone yet</h1>
        <p>Get following to fill your feed with just the stuff you wanna see</p>
    </section>
    <article class="d1-d3 t1-t4 m-all user_following">
    {{ member:profile uid="{author}" }}
        <a href="/profile/{{ username }}" class="user_avatar d1 m1">{{ gravatamatic:quicky
          email = "{email}"
          size  = "64"
         }}</a>
            <section class="d2-d3 m2-m4 author_bio">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</p>
                <a class="global_btn_white" href="/">Follow {{ username }}</a>
            </section>
    {{ /member:profile }}
    </article>
</div>
```

My JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        $('#hideshow').on('click', function(event) {        
             $('.following_prompt').toggle('show');
        });
    });
```

Comment: `$('.following_prompt').hide()`

Comment: That's the one - cheers Satish :)

Comment: or you could use ` $('.following_prompt').toggle();` and move the button up outside the div the toggles so it can show/hide on click

Answer (score 1):

Simple Fix - Thanks Satish

`$('.following_prompt').hide()`

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `hidden` class:

```
.hidden {display: none;}
```

And use:

```
$('.following_prompt').toggleClass('hidden');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this.,

`$('.following_prompt').hide()`

```js
  $('#hideshow').on('click', function(event) {        
         $('.following_prompt').hide();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="d-all t-all m-all group following_prompt">
<button type='button' id='hideshow' value='hide/show' class="close"><span class="icon-cross black right">close</span></button>
<section class="center group">
    <h1>You're not following anyone yet</h1>
    <p>Get following to fill your feed with just the stuff you wanna see</p>
</section>
<article class="d1-d3 t1-t4 m-all user_following">
{{ member:profile uid="{author}" }}
    <a href="/profile/{{ username }}" class="user_avatar d1 m1">{{ gravatamatic:quicky
      email = "{email}"
      size  = "64"
     }}</a>
        <section class="d2-d3 m2-m4 author_bio">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</p>
            <a class="global_btn_white" href="/">Follow {{ username }}</a>
        </section>
{{ /member:profile }}
</article>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

or you could use `$('.following_prompt').toggle();` and move the button up outside the div the toggles so it can show/hide on click

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jbnown69/)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        $('#hideshow').on('click', function(event) {        
             $('.following_prompt').toggle();
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type='button' id='hideshow' value='hide/show' class="close"><span class="icon-cross black right">Button</span></button><div class="d-all t-all m-all group following_prompt">

    <section class="center group">
        <h1>You're not following anyone yet</h1>
        <p>Get following to fill your feed with just the stuff you wanna see</p>
    </section>
    <article class="d1-d3 t1-t4 m-all user_following">
    {{ member:profile uid="{author}" }}
        <a href="/profile/{{ username }}" class="user_avatar d1 m1">{{ gravatamatic:quicky
          email = "{email}"
          size  = "64"
         }}</a>
            <section class="d2-d3 m2-m4 author_bio">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</p>
                <a class="global_btn_white" href="/">Follow {{ username }}</a>
            </section>
    {{ /member:profile }}
    </article>
</div>
```